# Bigquery: How to See Preview of "View Schema" Without Querying

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, schema

I am relatively new to Bigquery on Google Cloud Platform.

Table schema provides the user with three options "SCHEMA", "DETAILS", and "PREVIEW" where "PREVIEW" allows you to see a selection of rows from the data file.

However, "View schema" only provides the user with two options: "SCHEMA", and "DETAILS"

How can I "PREVIEW" a "View schema" without querying from the actual table?

Thank you

Comment: BQ doesn't support that functionality (yet???).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there a way to overcome this?I do not know what information is in these TiB data files I have to work with

Comment: . . You can select from the tables.  If that is expensive, you can do a one-time extract and use that to familiarize yourself with the data.

Comment: What's your table type? Can you share the details informations in your questions?

Comment: Could you please update the question with an example schema that you are trying to view?